# Ember.js 2.x: Call a helper from another helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to call a helper from another helper in my `ember.js` app and can't figure out how the blazes to do it in 2.x. For reference, I'm using Ember 2.4 with Ember-CLI.

There are several answers floating around that work in older versions; for example, the snippet below defines a helper variant which tries to work some magic and then call Ember's built-in `component` helper...

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function magicComponent(params) {
    // ...
    // do some magic here
    // ...

    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers['component'].apply(this, args); // Oops!
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(magicComponent);
```

...but the line marked 'Oops!' is TypeErroring, since `Ember.Handlebars.helpers` is `undefined` in Ember 2.x. Welp.

Does anyone know how to go about programmatically calling a helper (or setting up some sort of inheritance) in the latest Ember versions?

[EDIT] Removed references to 'Handlebars' for clarity.

Comment: Ember >= 1.10 uses HTMLbars not Handlebars. For the the official way to write helpers see here https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/templates/writing-helpers/

Comment: Do you have a specific use case you need this for?

Comment: @nem: I'm trying to keep the question itself use-case agnostic, since it's not going to help future Googlers who are wondering how to do this particular thing. I'm exploring other options myself, though, just in case, though that's outside the scope a bit.

Comment: Sure, but the reason I am asking is that importing a helper requires knowing **which helper** so we know **from where** to import it. You've clarified that you want to import a built-in helper, which is what I asked for :)

Comment: I explicitly stated that I'm using Ember's `component` helper in the question -- was it unclear? Asking for real, not sarcastically.

Comment: Yeah, I guess i somehow missed it, sorry about that. Btw, [here's a good read for this use case](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/programmatically-rendering-ember-components/6986/15).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, to add session based date format and timezone to [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

import MomentFormat from 'ember-moment/helpers/moment-format';

export default MomentFormat.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service(),

    formatChanged: observer("session.timeZone", "session.dateFormat", function() {
        this.recompute();
    }),


    compute([date], { locale }) {
        const timeZone = this.get("session.timeZone");
        const format = this.get("session.dateFormat");
        return this._super([date, format], {locale, timeZone});
    }
});
```

So basically, include the helper you need, and then extend it, and override the compute method.

Comment: Import & Extend indeed seems to be the correct answer, though I'm sorta scratching my head since this works great for custom helpers... but my original use case was figuring out how to call a core Ember helper (e.g. 'component' or 'link-to'). I may have just been too specific in my scenario for the actual question.